# Moringa yellowing & leaf drop

Tags: plant-health

The plant was growing well for a few months but in the last month or so the lower leaves started to yellow as the plant continued to grow rapidly.  The rate yellowing and dropping of the leaves is starting to overtake the new growth.

I live in the Middle Eastern desert, I keep the plant outdoors, it receives full sun from early morning till early afternoon.  It is adequately watered.  Just dealt with a bout of spider mites and whitefly with daily monitoring and treatment.

I am desperately trying to get the plant healthy before the winter months start to set in.

[image: Moringa]

Comment: It's in regular potting soil, I haven't added any fertilizer.  I have another plant that is growing much better even though it's in the shade.  It's in the same potting medium.

Comment: They go wild here in Israel.  I have a second plant that is doing very well.  Although you can't see, the plant is still putting out new leaves and even starting to bloom.  It has been outside for several months in pretty much the same conditions but just recently started to lose leaves.

Comment: I just moved it to a more shaded area a couple of days ago to see if it makes a difference.  The 2nd plant that's in the shade has very minimal yellowing.

Answer (score 2):

This is chemical imbalance.  You need to add a balanced fertilizer to potted plants and all plants you grow.  It has to be done carefully, too much will kill, but the only way plants are able to make their own food/nutrients is having the proper chemistry in the soil.  Especially plants in pots.  We are responsible for supplying soil, drainage, light, water and fertilizer.  I'd get a simple extended release balanced fertilizer such as Osmocote 14-14-14, use half of what they recommend.

Photosynthesis is the process plants make their own food and without Nitrogen, Phosphorus, Potassium, Boron, Iron, Molybdenum, Manganese, Copper, silica...photosynthesis can't happen.  The plant dies slowly.  The first three are critical.  There are many more of the micronutrients that are necessary in minute amounts and by observing your plants one can tell what is lacking or in excess.  But if you don't have those first 3 you have a plant that is dying.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably magnesium sulfate deficiency. Add Epsom salt solution to soil. Fish/kelp helps as it contains all the nutrients needed for moringa.
Be careful not to over water.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both answers 1 & 2.  I believe 
 Magnesium is the nutrient responsible for moving other nutrients from the soil UP throughout the plant.  I believe this is the problem.

If the plant is lacking magnesium other nutrients aren't getting throughout the plant in sufficient quantities either.  Good idea to apply fertilizer.  I use a 10-10-10 and cut that in half with good results.  I mostly use Epson a salt, banana peelings and coffee as their nutrients are readily available to the plant.